# How to use GetAsyncKeyState without calling it multiple times?

Tags: c++

This is how my code currently looks like:

```
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x31)) {
        //...
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x32)) {
        //...
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x33)) {
        //...
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x34)) {
        //...
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(0x35)) {
        //...
    }
```

Is there some more efficient way of doing this without calling GetAsyncKeyState multiple times per loop? Maybe store the function value into an integer and then use a switch statement?

Also, I do not want to use RegisterHotKey.

Comment: I can think of valid reasons to use `GetAsyncKeyState` -- namely, debugging.  Quite possibly you should not be doing any task in a UI thread that takes long enough for `GetAsyncKeyState` to differ from `GetKeyState` in any reliable way.  And `GetKeyboardState` returns an array of the entire keyboard state (as determined by what messages have been processed)...

Comment: Can't put it in a function? `if (keyDown(VK_CONTROL)) {if (keyDown(0x31)) {...}}`

Comment: @Yakk: I want the hotkeys to be as close as possible to the hardware. They have to be pressed while a full screen application is running that also takes keyboard input. There is no UI.

Comment: @chris: If I can keep it unmanaged, that would be great.

Comment: @user2370738, Hooking that application might be in your best interest, then, if this is only meant to do this while it's running.

Comment: @Yakk: Would you say GetKeyboardState is more efficient than my code above? Wouldn't GetKeyboardState get all the keys so that would take longer, right?

Comment: Pro-tip: The Windows virtual key codes for the numbers and alphabet are identical to their ASCII values.  So you can make your code more self-documenting by calling `GetAsyncKeyState('1')`, `GetAsyncKeyState('2')`, etc...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, For some reason unknown to man, even though that's true, I still prefer using the numeric values for 0-9 and A-Z. It's probably because the program is ever so slightly more portable, which is pointless when using the Windows API anyway :p

Comment: @chris In what way is it more portable?  I can think of ways it is less portable (if contrived ones), but I cannot think of a way that using `0x35` is more portable.

Comment: @Yakk, I'm just thinking about EBCDIC when I say that. In there, `'5'` would give you 0xF5. That's why I said it's completely and utterly useless thinking about that in relation to the Windows API, because no system you're going to be using this with is going to be using EBCDIC. There's the very few who have to work with it in general, and I guarantee zero here.

Comment: @user2370738 You are optimizing prematurely.  Premature optimization makes code slower, not faster, because you make the code harder to make faster in ways that actually matter.  `GeAsyncKeyState` differs from `GetKeyboardState` in ways that actually matter that have little to do with copying 256 bytes of memory.  Your program has a message pump, right?  The thread that is processing user input -- keyboard input -- would be what I am calling the UI thread.

Comment: @Yakk: Perhaps he's doing cross-compilation for Windows from an IBM mainframe.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley granted!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, :), just :) . If you're doing that, you'd better know about it anyway :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some tips.
0. Calling the func is slower than using a value directly.
1. The if-else statement can build a tree.The tree should be optimized by path compression.
You can promote your code like this.

```
static bool keys[256];
int getkey(){          //Don't forget to call this  before querying the "keys" array.
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
          GetAsyncKeyState(i);
    return 0;
}
if(keys[VK_CONTROL])
{
    if (keys[0x31]) {
        //...
    }

    if (keys[0x32]) {
       //...
    }

    if (keys[0x33]) {
        //...
    }

    if (keys[0x34]) {
        //...
    }

    if (keys[0x35]) {
        //...
    }
}
```